# Updating offline Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, updates

I have an ubuntu server which is offline and it doesn't has any external IP to connect to the Internet. I would like to update this server.

Would be possible through another ubuntu server which is online using the networks internal IP to make this?

Comment: If it has no external ip then the only way to connect to it is through the internal ip that assign to it.  As for doing what you want, unlikely, since the traffic on an internal network is not exposed to anyone outside of the network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom repository as shown [here](http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2011/06/27/setting-up-a-simple-ubuntu-apt-repository/).
Of course you will have to download the latest packages.

Comment: hm that looks good!

Comment: thank I could use the internal ip to access the repo isn't it